# Element's bottom margin/padding in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

Im working on the homepage of a webshop and im having a small problem that i cant overcome.
Check out [this link](http://www.lumeatapetului.ro/ro/nouapagina) and look beneath the "Produse Noi" header-text in the left side of the page.
There is a table divided in 2 columns,one with other-heading-texts and the other is containing several small images.

My problem is that in IE,the td is showing some space on the bottom of the images,while on mozilla works fine.

I tried putting "margin:0;padding:0;" on many elements in that area,but with no success.
So,how can i remove that space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The space at the bottom is white spaces, you use them to separate the links but put them after the last one. If you remove the last set the problem goes away.

Comment: +1 I was working on the same solution. Confirmed this via Fiddler.